# How to find the best regression model fit for your plot

Tags: r, regression, tidyverse, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

let's say I wish to fit a regression model to `disp ~ drat` from the `mtcars` dataset. Is there a package I can use that can tell me what type of regression I should use e.g. linear, polynomial, bayesian etc.?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, drat)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

Comment: Even if that existed, you shouldn't use it. (I'm concerned by your examples. They are all orthogonal to each other, i.e., you could fit a model that is linear, polynomial and Bayesian).

Comment: Here is a book that may help [Tidy Modeling with R](https://www.tmwr.org/) by Max Kuhn and Julia Silge.

Comment: Outside of `R`,  there's this cool thing  'eureqa'   https://www.datarobot.com/nutonian/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointing out the suggestion from **@Roland** you should do some exploratory and visual analysis to understand your data first. You can try with `stat_smooth()` and then decide what kind of model you want to fit:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, drat)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~cyl)+
  stat_smooth(se=F)+
  stat_smooth(color='magenta',method = 'lm',se=F)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all comments! So you would decide on the model solely by visual analysis and not e.g. adj.R2, P or AIC?